# KubernetesPodOperator, mounting a Secret as volume creates symlink

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-secrets

KubernetesPodOperator, mounting a Secret as volume creates symlink. Application that needs to access secret (cert file) requires path to file and not symlink

I mounted a `Secret` object to my `KubernetesPodOperator`. Going inside the containers instance, if I do the `ls -la` command, I can see the files but represented as symlinks:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 Jun  2 11:49 my_cert.pem -> ..data/my_cert.pem
```

When the application runs, it will error out because it requires path to the physical file and not the symlink.

How do I mount the Secret object so that it will mount the physical file?

Even worse is that if I follow the symlink, I noticed the file size is zero.

Comment: "mounted a Secret object to my KubernetesPodOperator" could you please describe how exactly did you do that?

Comment: Get the cert: `app_certs = Secret(deploy_type='volume', deploy_target="/certs", secret='my-app-certs') ` 
...then add the cert to KubernetesPodOperator definition/configuration: 
`my_pod = KubernetesPodOperator(secrets=[app_certs],
                      ...)`

Comment: This is no longer an issue for me. The app that uses the cert works. I thought the issue is on the cert path being a symlink.

Comment: please consider leaving an Answer for the Question if it works now.